# Sync two MVC4 (razor) pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On my main page, I have a textbox with a button called "Set" next to it. When a user clicks on the set button, it opens up a new page like a popup which have list of items with select button users can select.

When a user clicks on a select button, I wanted to sync the corresponding information into the my main page's text box.

Do anyone know how this could be done?

Index HTML Code:

`<input type="button" id="Set" name="Set..." value="Set..." class="btn btn-default" />`

Index Jquery Code:

```
$("#Set").click(function () {
            window.open('@Url.Action("FileTypeDefinitionSelector", "FileTypeDetails")', '', 'height=500,width=600,left=-150,top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
        });
```

List html code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Summary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { name=item.Name.Replace(" ", "") }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: You need to show your views

Comment: I've put the codes I currently have

Comment: `window.open` opens a new browser tab (not a 'pop-up'). You need to replace your current view with the new view  (by using a link, not `window.open`) and then redirect back to the original view.